# Better way to find absolute paths during os.walk()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, python-os

I am practicing with the `os` module and more specifically `os.walk()`. I am wondering if there is an easier/more efficient way to find the actual path to a file considering this produces a path that suggests the file is in the original folder when `os.walk()` is first ran:

```
import os

threshold_size = 500

for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for file in files:
        filePath = os.path.abspath(file)
        if os.path.getsize(filePath) >= threshold_size:
            print filePath, str(os.path.getsize(filePath))+"kB"
```

This is my current workaround:

```
import os

threshold_size = 500

for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    path = os.path.abspath(folder)
    for file in files:
        filePath = path + "\\" + file
        if os.path.getsize(filePath) >= threshold_size:
            print filePath, str(os.path.getsize(filePath))+"kB"
```

For shaktimaan, this:

```
for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for file in files:
        filePath = os.path.abspath(file)
        print filePath
```

produces this(most of these files are in a subfolder of projects, not projects itself):

```
C:\Python27\projects\ps4.py
C:\Python27\projects\ps4_encryption_sol.py
C:\Python27\projects\ps4_recursion_sol.py
C:\Python27\projects\words.txt
C:\Python27\projects\feedparser.py
C:\Python27\projects\feedparser.pyc
C:\Python27\projects\news_gui.py
C:\Python27\projects\news_gui.pyc
C:\Python27\projects\project_util.py
C:\Python27\projects\project_util.pyc
C:\Python27\projects\ps5.py
C:\Python27\projects\ps5.pyc
C:\Python27\projects\ps5_test.py
C:\Python27\projects\test.py
C:\Python27\projects\triggers.txt
C:\Python27\projects\ps6.py
C:\Python27\projects\ps6_pkgtest.py
C:\Python27\projects\ps6_solution.py
C:\Python27\projects\ps6_visualize.py
C:\Python27\projects\ps6_visualize.pyc
C:\Python27\projects\capitalsquiz1.txt
C:\Python27\projects\capitalsquiz2.txt
C:\Python27\projects\capitalsquiz3.txt
C:\Python27\projects\capitalsquiz4.txt
C:\Python27\projects\capitalsquiz5.txt
C:\Python27\projects\capitalsquiz_answers1.txt
C:\Python27\projects\capitalsquiz_answers2.txt
C:\Python27\projects\capitalsquiz_answers3.txt
C:\Python27\projects\capitalsquiz_answers4.txt
C:\Python27\projects\capitalsquiz_answers5.txt
C:\Python27\projects\quiz.py
C:\Python27\projects\file2.txt
C:\Python27\projects\regexes.txt
C:\Python27\projects\regexsearch.py
C:\Python27\projects\testfile.txt
C:\Python27\projects\renamedates.py
```

Comment: You should use `filePath = os.path.join(path, file)` instead of `filePath = path + "\\" + file`

Comment: Oh duh! I just learned about the join method and it didn't even cross my mind. How come the `os.path.abspath` isn't returning the correct absolute path though?

Comment: I tried running this on my system and `os.path.abspath` is returning correct path. Can you upload the output that you get while using abspath??

Comment: [rtfm](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk), there is even example with obtaining full path.

Answer (score 7):

I think there you mistook what `abspath` does. abspath just convert a relative path to a complete absolute filename.

For e.g.

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.join(r"c:\users\anonymous\", ".."))
#produces this output : c:\users
```

Without any other information, `abspath` can only form an absolute path from the only directory it can know about, for your case the current working directory. So currently what it is doing is it joins `os.getcwd()` and your `file`

So what you would have to do is:

```
for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for file in files:
        filePath = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(folder), file)
```

Comment: Thank you @shaktimaan.. This explanation and along with code, helped me to understand concept better

Answer (score 2):

Your work around should work fine, but a simpler way to do this would be:

```
import os

threshold_size = 500

root = os.getcwd()
root = os.path.abspath(root) # redunant with os.getcwd(), maybe needed otherwise
for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(root):
    for file in files:
        filePath = os.path.join(folder, file)
        if os.path.getsize(filePath) >= threshold_size:
            print filePath, str(os.path.getsize(filePath))+"kB"
```

The basic idea here is that `folder` will be an absolute normalized path if the argument to `os.walk` is one and `os.path.join` will produce an absolute normalized  path if any of the arguments is an absolute path and all the following arguments are normalized.

The reason why `os.path.abspath(file)` doesn't work in your first example is that `file` is a bare filename like `quiz.py`. So when you use `abspath` it does essentially the same thing `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file)` would do.

Answer (score 1):

This simple example should do the trick.
I have stored the result in a list, because for me it's quite handy to pass the list to a different function and execute different operations on a list.

```
import os
directory = os.getcwd()
list1 = []

for root, subfolders, files in os.walk(directory):
  list1.append( [ os.path.join(os.path.abspath(root), elem) for elem in files if elem ])
# clean the list from empty elements
final_list = [ x for x in list1 if x != [] ]
```